# how to use javascript in jinja template in flask

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask

i wish to call the JavaScript function on the Jinga button, `oninput = input_filename()`. But the button doesn't trigger. What am I doing wrong? Please I need help .

```
{{ form.video_file(onclick="upload('{{ request.url }}');", id="v", class="btn btn-primary", class="custom-file-input", id="file_input", oninput="input_filename()") }}<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake i made was that the JavaScript code for the function, oninput = input_filename(),  was placed after the {% endblock %} i.e outside the {% block content %}. To solve this problem, the JavaScript code was moved above the {% endblock %} i.e inside the {% block content %}